# Bookshelf, Knex and mysql to save a list of an object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am very confused to use Bookshelf model to insert data to database in this situation:

I am using these libs:
knex, bookshelf, express, body-parser, and mysql database

I have a table on db is called location, it contains below column:
`loc_id`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `time`

This location is sending from one user, so I need to save `loc_id` in another table with `user_id`

to save a location (single object) without saving user_id I use this code:

```
.post(function (req, res) {

    Loc.forge({latitude: req.body.location.lat,
                  longitude: req.body.location.lng,
                  date:req.body.time,
                  speed:req.body.speed,
                  gpsAnten:req.body.gpsAnten})
    .save()
    .then(function (location) {
      res.json({error: false, data: {id: location.get('id')}});
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
    });
  });
```

but now, I am sending post request by body like below from my device:(it is JSON format)

```
{
  "user_id": 135,
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "latitude": "35.374760",
      "longitude": "51.5123916",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "latitude": "35.6247466",
      "longitude": "51.51241",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "latitude": "35.6247466",
      "longitude": "51.51241",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "latitude": "35.6247466",
      "longitude": "51.51241",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "latitude": "35.6247466",
      "longitude": "51.51241",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "latitude": "35.6247466",
      "longitude": "51.51241",
      "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      }
  ]
}
```

How could I save each location in `location` table and get this Id, then save its `loc_id` and `user_id` in `loc_user` table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I found the solution to fix this issue; here is my code:

```
  .post(function (req, res) {

deviceId = req.body.id

locationArray = req.body.frame;
locationArray.forEach(function(element) {
console.log(element);
Loc.forge({latitude: element.location.lat,
              longitude: element.location.lng,
              date: element.time,
              speed: element.speed,
              gpsAnten: element.gpsAnten})
.save()
.then(function (location) {
 userDevice.forge({
   device_id: deviceId,
   location_id: location.get('id')
 })
 .save()
 .then(function(middleware) {
   console.log('Save middleware');
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
   console.log('Error middleware:' + err.message);
 })
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log('Error location:' + err.message);
});
   });
  });
```

It is not as clear as I need but seems is only solution.